# How to edit all values of a column in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to edit all the values in a specific column (`'ISSN1'`) of a dataframe (`df1`) in pandas. An example value of this column is `1234-5678` and I would like it to be modified in order to remove the `-` (thus obtaining `12345678`).

If I do this:

```
print(df1)

for elem in df1.ISSN1:
    elem = str(elem).replace("-", "")

print(df1)
```

The dataframe results in being apparently unchanged and I get no error message. Why? How can I remove the dash in all values of the `'ISSN1'` column? Notice that some values are `NaN`.

I found some answers using lambdas but I find it a little confusing and since I am still learning I would prefer an answer that doesn't include lambdas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply`:

```
df1['ISSN1'] = df1['ISSN1'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace('-', '')
```

Or `pd.Series.str` method:

```
df1['ISSN1'] = df1['ISSN1'].astype(str).str.replace('-', '')
```

If your column contains only strings and possibly `np.nan` you can remove `astype(str)`:

```
df1['ISSN1'] = df1['ISSN1'].str.replace('-', '')
```